# Trying to find a resealable bottle cap

Tags: bottles, preservation

A long long time ago (.. I can still remember ♫) there were these old bottle caps. My parents still have 2 or 3 at home from soviet times. They look kinda like this:

[image]

What are those called? Ar there some keywords to find them? It took me at least 3- minutes to even find this image (and it was in  middle of completely unrelated images down on something like the third image-search page). Or, the best option, where can I buy a box of these?

**P.S.** I know that the image is from "flip-top" wikipedia page, but what I am looking for is a cap, that is independent from the bottle itself.

Comment: whats about `reusable flip top seal`?

Comment: Grolsch is the name

Comment: Are you sure you want that type of cap? The beer that uses that re-sealable cap is Grolsch. It seems to me that would be an unnecessary expense just for aesthetics. The beer is what's important.

Comment: @user15363 Because when I open a bottle of beer and need to leave immediately, I don't want for it to go to waste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found what I was looking for: [WESTMARK 3 Flaschenverschlüsse, Flaschenstöpsel mit Hebel und Gummidichtung, 40 x 60 x 15 mm, farblich sortiert](https://www.danto.de/Wohnen-Einrichten/Barmoebel-accessoires/Flaschenhalter/WESTMARK-3-Flaschenverschluesse-Flaschenstoepsel-mit-Hebel-und-Gummidichtung-40-x-60-x-15-mm-farblich-sortiert.html).

[image: Westmark 3]

Now I only need to order a box of these.

Answer (score 0):

In the USA you can find this type of cap at most homebrew shops. These originated in Holland but now are popular for many breweries around the world. Here are the [caps](https://www.morebeer.com/products/flip-top-swing-cap.html)

Comment: Those require special bottles, where the lip of the bottle has two indentations, where those hinges go in. I was aiming at something I can use one a "normal bottle".

Comment: See my answer to this question if you don't care about the way you seal the bottle. https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/7003/can-i-re-cork-a-beer-bottle